# MongoDB return an empty array in nodeJS Serverless App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to retrieve the terms of services for an application using the appId passed as a parameter in the URL. URL should be:
apps/{appsId}/tos
With the code below I get the appId via the url parameters and I search in mongo's request for the corresponding id. However when I test with postman I result in an empty array.
Can someone help me?

getAppTos lib

```
import MongoClient from '../../libs/mongoClient';

const {
  COLL_TOS,
  DB_NAME,
} = process.env;

export const getAppTos = async (appId) => {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect();
  try {
    const tosbyapp = await client
      .db(DB_NAME)
      .collection(COLL_TOS)
      .find({
        appIds: { $elemMatch: { $eq: appId } },
      }).toArray();
    return tosbyapp;
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
};
```

getAppTos handler

```
import { getAppTos } from '../lib/getAppTos';
import response from '../../libs/httpResponses/response';

export default async (event) => {
  const { appId } = event.pathParameters.id;

  try {
    const results = await getAppTos(appId);

    if (results === false) {
      return response({ code: 404, message: 'tos_not_found' });
    }
    return response({ code: 200, body: results });
  } catch (e) {
    return response({ code: 500, message: e.message });
  }
};
```

serverless.yml

```
getAppTos:
      handler: handlers/getAppTos.default
      events:
        - http:
            path: apps/{id}/tos
            method: get
            cors: true
            request:
              parameters:
                paths:
                  id: true
```

Example of a document in my collection termsOfServices :
[image]

Comment: 1. go to CLI session  ( mongo shell ) and work there until u have the expression that gets the need document ok  2. translate success from 1  to Postman , working there until you have the http related Get working 3. return to your JS Get and if you console log the http expression for the fetch in JS , then u should get same , success as in 2 with postman

Comment: Thanks @RobertRowntree , I used this whole method and I made a mistake when I retrieved the app id, I put braces and I didn't have to! thank you for allowing me to unblock my problem with a logical path